# CSS how to page break a table after reaching exactly above footer and continue the table at the same height?

Tags: html, css

[image]

Is there a way to page break at the red line (exactly above footer) and then set the table of the next page starting from the same height as the table on the first page? I have tried setting height or max-height for starters on the table but they are not working. Header from title up to the line above table and the footer (sign area) are fixed positioned to allow duplicates across all print pages.

```css
@media print {  
      @page { 
      size: 21.59cm 13.97cm;
    } 

    html, body{
      width:100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .numeric{
      text-align:right;
    }

    .invoice{
      font-size: 0.7em;
      height:100%;
    }

    header, footer{
      position:fixed;
      width:100%;
      display:block;
    }
    
    #buyerCompany{
      padding-left: 10%;
    }

    .column{
      display: inline-block;
      width: 33%;
      
    }
    
    .info {
      display: table;
    }

    .info h3 {
      display: table-row;
    }

    .info span{
      display: table-cell;
      padding-right: 2mm;
      padding-top: 1.5mm;
    }

     table{
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 1em;
        border-top: solid 1px black;
        position: absolute;
        top:25%;
        max-height:50px;
        page-break-inside:auto;
      }

      table tbody tr{
        height:1em;
      }

      table td, table th{
        border-left: solid 1px black;
        border-right: solid 1px black;
        padding-left: 1mm;
        padding-right: 1mm;
        vertical-align:text-top; 
      }

      table, table th{
        border-bottom: solid 1px black;
      }

      table, table th{
        border: solid 1px black;
      }

      table #note td, table #subtotal td, table #discount td{
        border-top: none;
        border-bottom: none;
      }

      table #subtotal{
        border-top: solid 1px black;
      }

      table #grandTotal{
         border-bottom: solid 1px black;
       }

      table #note{
        height: 3em;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      table tfoot{
        display:table-row-group;
        page-break-after: avoid;
        page-break-inside: avoid;     
      }

      h3 {
        line-height:1em;
      }

      footer {
        display: flex;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 30%;
        text-align:center;
      }

      .sign:nth-child(2){
        margin-left: 5em;
      }
      
      .sign:last-child{
        margin-left: 5em;
      }

      .sign h3{
        padding-bottom: 3em;
      }
    }
  `;
```